# How to align QGIS legend items to the right?

Tags: qgis, legend, print-composer, alignment

Is there a way to align QGIS map composer legend items to the right, for right-to-left languages? 
There is only a title alignment option.
Furthermore, I found this ticket from 4 years ago regarding same issue: [trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/3239](https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/3239)

My current workaround is to add spaces in item name, but that only aligns the text, not the symbol obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still an open issue. The ticket on the current bug tracker is http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3239

I imagine a few users with interest in right-to-left languages could easily fund this together.

Comment: Thanks Anita. I've looked at the sponsorship options for QGIS, and there's a disclaimer regarding lack of "earmarked features". If so, what are the options for this feature to be prioritized higher than "Future release - nice to have"?
On a side note, as Arabic is included in the QGIS translations, and a growing Hebrew speaking QGIS community, it would seem a good enough reason, and high demand, for such a feature.

Comment: The best approach is to contact a developer or some company offering commercial support directly. The disclaimer just means that the project cannot organize these targeted developments.

Comment: @hdunn I'd be happy to discuss this further with you. Send me an email at nyall.dawson@gmail.com if you want to follow up.

Comment: @underdark I am also interested in some right-to-left features to be included in Qgis, my question is how to fund specific feature?