# Changing alignment of symbol in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

How can we change the symbol to be in right side and the label description will be in the left side in qgis 3.6?

Comment: Some details on what type of features you're talking about, as well as a visualisation of your desired output would be great.

Comment: There is no way currently to automatically put the symbol to the right and description to the left. But here is a workaround solution to the same problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295316/change-legend-right-to-left-reading-in-qgis

Comment: There's a [request for this feature](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/3239) from 8 years ago. 3 years ago it was updated from 0% to 10% done. At that rate, we can expect this to be implemented in the year 2061.